# DLL files are incorrect size when uploaded to server via FTP

Tags: ftp, .net, dll

I've set up a new server with FTP access. However I have noticed that when uploading .dll (.net assembly) files via FTP, the destination file is a different size to the original file.

This seems to prevent the assembly loading in the application.

If I copy the same .DLL via RDP, all is fine. There is roughly a 3k difference.

I've checked the file transfer type which is 'I' - correct for this kind of file.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I would ensure you upload the content using binary mode. You might be transferring in ASCII mode.